# Table css property not changing after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Initially my table *display is none* so its not visible in my application i am using ajax call so when the user selects any option a table is generated and the initiall display property which was set to be none changes to block and it becomes visible but my table is not getting visible.Please suggest.

**Ajax works fine its only the display property not getting changed**

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
function checkbrand(str) {
    document.getElementById("first").style.display="block";
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {

            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","test1.php?m="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

**PHP CODE**

```
     <?php
        session_start();
       require('connect.php');
       $m = $_GET['m'];
       $skuarray=array();
       $p=$_SESSION['Head_item_id'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `major_item_table` where Head_item_id=$p";
$query=$handler->query($sql);
echo '<select id="category" onchange="checkbrand(this.value)";>';
echo '<option selected="selected">Select SubCategory</option>';
while($r=$query->fetch())
{   
    echo "<option>". $r['Major_item_name']."</option>";

}
echo '</select>';

        echo '<div id="first" style="display:none">'; 
        echo '<table>
        <tr>
        <th>SKU</th>
        <th>Vendor_Id</th>
        <th>Rates_Entered</th>
        <th>Rate_Shown_On_Website</th>
        <th>Date_Time</th>
        <th>Rate_Type</th>
        </tr>';
        echo '</table>';
      ?>
```

Comment: Where’s the element with the `brand` ID? Are you sure you didn’t mean the `<div>` with the ID `first`?

Comment: So what triggers the `checkbrand` function? Where is the script placed in your page? Did you check the console for errors (F12)? Your `<table>` isn't closed?

Comment: it is in separate html file @Xufox

Comment: i have added code for that @adeneo

Comment: What is `url` of your php file?

Comment: What is the value of `str` in javascript file?

Comment: it is the value of option selected @ZainFarooq

Comment: Is it working fine? If your url isn't correct then you can not send data to php file

Comment: ajax is working fine its only the display property not getting changed@ZainFarooq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkbrand(str) {
   document.getElementById("first").style.display="block";    
   if (str == "") {
}// End of function

setInterval(function(){checkbrand(str)},1000);//You can pass your argument by yourself
```

You need to use `setInterval`. It calls this function after interval of time. Here I have set it for 1 sec. You can try this. Hope It will help you.

Comment: but i want to set this when use selects any option and hence document.getElementById("first").style.display="block"; should be inside function checkbrand @Zain Farooq

Comment: I think your javascript function is not running properly or probably you need to refresh your page to run this javascript code.